# display array on same page

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array but cant get it to display on the same page on submit. The form works how it should, displaying what was chosen next to it. If its not filled it it shows that something needs to be put in. What am I doing wrong so the array wont display on the same page?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Ex 2</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
function checkForm(){

    var chk = true;
    var mName = document.getElementById("txtM");
    var meth = document.getElementById("methM");
    var rad = document.getElementById("radM");
    var sel = document.getElementById("selM");
    var heal = document.getElementById("a");
    var dark = document.getElementById("b");
    var ele = document.getElementById("c");
    var wep = document.getElementById("imp");
    var last = document.getElementById("final");

    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
    var quotes = new Array()        
    quotes[0] = "You Are A Warrior"
    quotes[1] = "You Are A Mesmer"
    quotes[2] = "You Are A Elementalist"
    quotes[3] = "You Are A Necromancer"
    quotes[4] = "You Are A Guardian"
    document.write(quotes[randomnumber]);


        meth.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
        rad.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
        sel.setAttribute("style", "display:none");

    if (mName.value=='no'){     
        document.getElementById("methM").innerHTML = "No";
        meth.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if (mName.value=='yes'){        
        document.getElementById("methM").innerHTML = "Yes";
        meth.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if (mName.value==''){
        document.getElementById("methM").innerHTML = "So You Don't Like To Do Any Damage?";
        meth.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if (heal.checked) {
    document.getElementById("radM").innerHTML = "Healer";
    rad.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
    chk = false;
    }
    if (dark.checked) {
    document.getElementById("radM").innerHTML = "Dark";
    rad.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
    chk = false;
    }
    if (ele.checked) {
    document.getElementById("radM").innerHTML = "One with the Elements";
    rad.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
    chk = false;
    }   
    if (wep.value==1){
        document.getElementById("selM").innerHTML = "Rifle";
        sel.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if (wep.value==2){
        document.getElementById("selM").innerHTML = "Bow and Arrow";
        sel.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if (wep.value==3){
        document.getElementById("selM").innerHTML = "Daggers";
        sel.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }
    if (wep.value==0){
        document.getElementById("selM").innerHTML = "Gotta Have A Weapon!";
        sel.setAttribute("style", "display:inline");
        chk = false;
    }

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="page">   
<main role="main">
<article>
    <div id="errMess" class="errMess"></div>
      <h1>What Guild Wars 2 Profession Are You</h1>

        <div class="cssTable" style="margin-top:-25px;">
        <form method="post">
          <table>
          <tr><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td><div align="right">Do you like to do high damage?</div></td><td width="217">
            <input id="txtM" name="txtM" type="text" size="25"></td><td ><div id="methM" style="display:none"></div></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div align="right">What best describes you?</div></td><td>
                <input id="a" type="radio" name = "group1" value="A">Healer</input>
                <input id="b" type="radio" name = "group1" value="B">Dark</input>
                <input id="c" type="radio" name = "group1" value="C">Earthling</input>               
                </td><td><div id="radM" style="display:none"></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>What weapon would you like to have?</td>
                <td>
                <select id="imp"><option value="0" selected="true">Select One</option>
                <option value="1">Rifle</option>
                <option value="2">Bow and Arrow</option>
                <option value="3">Daggers</option></select>
                </td><td><div id="selM" style="display:none"></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="3" align="right"><input type="button" class="styled-button-7" value="Send" onclick="checkForm()"/></td></tr></table></form></div></article>
                </main></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using `document.write()`. That's a bad practice. To set style its like `sel.style.display = 'inline';`. Submission reloads the page completely. That means your JavaScript too. If you don't need to query another page just use JavaScript, otherwise AJAX.

Comment: it doesnt reload the page until the array was put in because everything was coming back false so it would display on the same page. just need the array to comeback false as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `chk` in your `checkForm()` callback for this work.

```
return chk;
```